# Android Q access external folders

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-external-storage, android-10.0

So I was having an issue with a few of my Android 10 users and them not being able to save or access the stored data on their device, I found out this is because Android 10 now says we can only access the data that the app itself created and only in the local folder?

So I went through and changed my code from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to `getExternalFilesDir(null)` and had them manually move the files over on their device and everything is back working correctly except one feature. I allow them to export data from the sqlite database on the app to CSV, how can I make it so this is still accessible on their downloads folder for Android 10 and not have to store this in my apps directory folder?

Comment: Why not use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` and let the *user* choose where to export the data?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SAF framework:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT); 
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); 
i.setType("text/csv"); 
String filename = "test.csv"; 
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, filename);
startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

then in onActivityResult:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
OutputStream os = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
//write your file here
```